# Use Auth/ResetPasswords in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a PasswordController in `/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller {

    use ResetsPasswords;
     ............
}
```

ResetPasswords has all the functionalities like getEmail, postEmail for resetting password.

```
public function getEmail()
{
    return view('auth.password');
}
```

I created a route:

```
Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
```

but its not working. Its throwing exception:

```
Class auth.driver does not exist
```

I am using laravel 5.0xx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change in your route method like:

```
Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@email');
```

To

```
Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
```

Comment: done but still getting errors : Class auth.driver does not exist

Answer (score 0):

change your route from

```
Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@email');
```

to

```
Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
```